# Verification by Card always shows Session Expired on Azure

Tags: session, azure, subscription

Whenever i try to register for Azure Free Trial, i feed all information and as soon as i land on Verification by Card page, it loads and then instantly shows me Session expired. I tried using different ID, different network and also different city to perform the action. Azure support does not work and googling doesnt help much either.

Is anyone else experiencing same or i am only one with such a problem.
I have also attached the screenshot of the issue.

[Azure Session Expired.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrLeG.png)

Comment: it seems unlikely that this is going to be answered outside of MS support - You could raise a support call [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=ClassicCommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=15470&ccsid=635827966273974972)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume only two thing could cause this.

**1. The Browser.**

Can you do a clean fresh install of your preferred browser? Maybe there is a cookie issue. Microsoft has a notorious browser past. Are you using IE? If not true installing IE.

**2. The Site's Code**

Nothing can be done there. Just call Microsoft Support.

I hope this helps.

Best,

Tim

Comment: I tried with internet explorer but it resulted in same. anyways I contacted MS support and they were able to take me through the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a global access issue with Azure, but you can double-check the status [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/).

It looks like a trouble with your current device configuration.

1. Check that your clock is correct. Your browser may remove cookies or
   reject certificates because of wrong clock.
2. Check your browser-specific settings for limitations and security measures like disabled Javascript or enchanced security. It's also worth checking the addons and extensions for the same reason.
3. If you're on Windows, check Internet Settings or try to add the site to Trusted Sites list. A few months ago I had to add Microsoft sites to the Trusted Sites list on Windows Server box to solve a similar issue.

The simplest solution would be to try another device.

Comment: it was all checked, no issues there, anyways MS support helped me through

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Trying different approaches to solve the issue ultimately had the same outcome...I couldn't create an Azure subscription when logging in using my O365 credentials.

Working with Microsoft Support the approach that successfully worked for me was to open an InPrivate Browser session. Navigate to https://account.azure.com/, which causes a credential challenge, which you should use the O365 credentials. Ultimately a successful outcome.

BTW> I could only engage MS Support by submitting a Support request. MSFT were responsive in that I was contacted within 60min, with a suggested resolution.